# store_result() and get_result() in mysql returns false

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I made a code a few days ago including `get_result()` to receave the results from my database. Today I wantet to add to it and fix some errors. So I tried to use `num_rows` to see if anything were returned. But for this I had to use `store_result()`. And when I do this `get_result()` just returns a boolean of false. When I comment out `store_result()` everything works as it should. 
I know that the `>=` will mess it up. But I put the `=` there for debugging(to comment out the `store_result()` and see what happend). So that is not the problem

```
$sql = $this->connect();
$a = $sql->prepare("SELECT `name`, `title`, `comment`, `date`  FROM `comment` WHERE `post`=?");
$a->bind_param("s", $id);
$a->execute();
$a->store_result();
if ($a->num_rows >= 0) {
    $res = $a->get_result();
    var_dump($res);

    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `get_result()` **instead** of `store_result()`, and then use the result object's `num_rows`:

```
$a->execute();
$res = $a->get_result();
if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results;
} else {
    return false;
}
```