# PHP- mysqli->num_rows always returns 0, Prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, prepared-statement, mysql-num-rows

First of all I would like to tell that I have already gone though **ALL DUPLICATE** questions. and tried the changes suggested there.

As far as now I have already tried changing `num_rows` to `num_rows()`
And using `store_result();` And using `affected_rows()`.

Also calling `store_result();` after `execute()`

I think there might be some other problem which I can't  figure out

```
$conn->autocommit(false);   
if ($sucess){
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE e_eventqueue SET e_urlfil=? WHERE e_id=? 
AND u_id=?");
    $stmt2->bind_param("iis",$e_urlfil,$e_id,$u_id);

    if($stmt2->execute()){
         $stmt2->store_result();
        echo "true";
        echo $stmt2->num_rows;  // <- this always return 0 even when its not
        $stmt2->close();
        $conn->commit();
    }
 else{
      $conn->rollback();
     echo "rollback";
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you actually updating anything? MySQL can report 0 rows affected if the `UPDATE` results in no change

Comment: For update query You need to check affected_rows . not num_rows

Comment: @Phil yes i am updating different values everytime which is visible in phpmyadmin

Comment: After execute check like this `$row_count= $stmt2->affected_rows;` If query executed successfully but no changes in data means it will return 0 .

Comment: FYI, for an `UPDATE` query, you should use `$stmt2->affected_rows`. You will **not** need to store the result, ie `$stmt2 = $conn->prepare(...); $stmt2->bind_param(...); $stmt2->execute(); echo $stmt2->affected_rows;`. Also, I'm not sure if `affected_rows` reports anything until the transaction is committed.

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253407/store-result-and-get-result-in-mysql-returns-false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1st :** For update query You need to check `affected_rows` . not `num_rows`

**2nd :**  After execute check like this `$row_count= $stmt2->affected_rows;` If query executed successfully but no changes in data means it will `return 0` .

```
if($stmt2->execute()){

    echo $stmt2->affected_rows; 
 }
```

**Affected_rows :**

Affected_rows  is for `insert,update,delete`

**Num_rows :**

Num_rows  is for `select`

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments above, check the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php

> Returns the total number of rows changed, deleted, or inserted by the last executed statement

http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

> Return the number of rows in statements result set